# What could hinder a shortcode from displaying properly?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

What could hinder a shortcode placed on a template file or a widget from displaying properly? We're using Wordpress. The shortcode displays the supposed content properly when directly placed on a post (like the main content of a page). But when you post it via a template file (a file supposed to be common to all pages), it just wouldn't show up. It would instead show the raw code.

By the way, the short code is for a form. The form doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Hi, Let me know the page link

Comment: Can you post the code you have written for displaying the shortcode on that template ?

Comment: thanks for the feedback but I finally found a solution to this issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it!

Since the shortcode is to be placed on a template file (PHP), it had to be passed into a `do_shortcode() function` so that instead of just the raw (example) `[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]`, it should be rendered as:

`<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]' ); ?>`